# Clustering with kmeans in R different centers after clustering

Tags: r, matrix, k-means

I defined centers matrix with samples of my data like above and uses this information in my kmeans function so after running kmeans I expect that after running `kmeansRslt$centers`. I see my center matrix but it's totally different with defined centers ?!

Is the first column of data not included in `kmeans` because it's row and `user_id` number?

```
#fun 
centersMatrix <- matrix(readyToCluster[279,],nrow=1,ncol=43)
#intellectual
centersMatrix <- rbind(centersMatrix,readyToCluster[13,])
#advanturous
centersMatrix <- rbind(centersMatrix,readyToCluster[276,])
#romantic
centersMatrix <- rbind(centersMatrix,readyToCluster[655,])
head(centersMatrix)

#kmeans with defined centers
kmeansRslt<-kmeans(readyToCluster[,2:43],centersMatrix[,2:43])

#size of each cluster
centersMatrix[,1:2]
kmeansRslt$centers[,1:2]
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @Pascal sorry the data is a little complicated

Comment: I don't see how we could help without a minimal example.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I posted a question here that has sample data so you can regenerate issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72177902/k-means-r-vs-k-means-python-different-cluster-values-generating-different-bar-gr