# K-Means R vs K-Means Python different cluster values generating different bar Graphs

Tags: python, r, cluster-analysis, k-means

Below are 2 sets of code that do the same thing one in Python the other in R. They both graph the Kmeans the same with respect to PCA but once I do the bar chart at the end using the cluster Center the Graphs are totally different. I believe there is something wrong about the Kmeans and the cluster calculation in python. The original code was provided in R. I am trying to see why the bar chart in python does not match are I believe its the centers. Please review and provide some feed back.

Please use the link below to download the data set I used to generate these graphs.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fhnxxrjl07y0h2c/TableStats2.csv?dl=0

R Code

```
## Retrive Libraries needed for script
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")
  

pcp <- read.csv(file='E:\\ProgramData\\R\\Code\\TableStats2.csv')

#Label each row with table Name to Plot names on chart.
data <- pcp
rownames(data) <- data[, 1]


#Gather all the data and leave out Table Names
data <- data[, -1]
data <- data[, -1]

#Create The PCA (Principle Component Analysis)
data <- scale(data)
pca <- prcomp(data)

plot.data <- data.frame(pca$x[, 1:2])

set.seed(2121)
clusters <- kmeans(data, 6)
plot.data$clusters <- factor(clusters$cluster)

g <- ggplot(plot.data, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, colour = clusters)) +
  geom_point(size = 3.5) +
  geom_text(label = rownames(data), colour = "darkgrey", hjust = .7) +
  theme_bw()

behaviours <- data.frame(clusters$centers)
behaviours$cluster <- 1:6
behavious <- melt(behaviours, "cluster")

g2 <- ggplot(behavious, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'identity', fill = "steelblue") +
  facet_wrap(~cluster) +
  theme_grey() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

python code

```
import pandas as pd    
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans    
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    
from plotnine import ggplot, aes, geom_line, geom_bar, facet_wrap, theme_grey, theme, element_text

TableStats = pd.read_csv(r'E:\ProgramData\R\Code\TableStats2.csv')

sc = StandardScaler()
pca = PCA()
tables = TableStats.iloc[:,0]
y = tables

features = ['Range Scans', 'Singleton Lookups', 'Row Locks', 'Row Lock Waits (ms)','Page Locks', 'Page Lock Waits (ms)', 'Page IO Latch Wait (ms)']
# Separating out the features
x = TableStats.loc[:, features].values

x = sc.fit_transform(x)
dpca = pca.fit_transform(x)
x1 = dpca[:,0]
y1 = dpca[:,1]
plt.figure(figsize=(20,11))
plot = plt.scatter(x1,y1, c=y.index.tolist())
for i, label in enumerate(y):
  #print(label)
  plt.annotate(label,(x1[i], y1[i]))
plt.show()

df = pd.DataFrame(dpca,columns = ['Range Scans', 'Singleton Lookups', 'Row Locks', 'Row Lock Waits (ms)','Page Locks', 'Page Lock Waits (ms)', 'Page IO Latch Wait (ms)']) 

clusters = KMeans(n_clusters=6,init='k-means++', random_state=2121).fit(df)

df['Cluster'] = clusters.labels_
df['Cluster Centroid D1'] = df['Cluster'].apply(lambda label: clusters.cluster_centers_[label][0])
df['Cluster Centroid D2'] = df['Cluster'].apply(lambda label: clusters.cluster_centers_[label][1])
df['tables'] = tables

#print Table Names
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 11))
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x=x1, y=y1, hue='Cluster', s=200, palette='coolwarm', legend=True)
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="Cluster Centroid D1", y="Cluster Centroid D2", hue='Cluster', s=1000, palette='coolwarm', legend=False, alpha=0.1)
for line in range(0,df.shape[0]):
    ax.text(x1[line]+0.05, y1[line],TableStats['Object Name'][line], horizontalalignment='left',size='medium', color='black',weight='semibold')

plt.legend(loc='upper right', title='Cluster')
ax.set_title("Clustered Points", fontsize='xx-large', y=1.05);
plt.show()

# here is where the R and Python graphs are different because the cluster centers dont match
behaviours = pd.DataFrame(clusters.cluster_centers_)
behaviours.columns = clusters.feature_names_in_
behaviours['cluster'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

b2 = pd.melt(behaviours, id_vars = "cluster",value_name="value")

(ggplot(b2, aes(x = 'variable', y = 'value')) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'identity', fill = "steelblue") + 
facet_wrap('~cluster') + 
theme_grey() + 
theme(axis_text_x = element_text(rotation = 90, hjust=1), figure_size=(20,8)) 
)
```

Comment: learn on how to ask a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hello onyambu. this code was actually reduced and it both have been tested and run. Thanks for the link. I will review is there anything with question that you believe is unclear?

Comment: If you know where the problem is, post an example of a dataset and the code to reproduce the erro. We do not need the whole code.

Comment: Thats just it there really is no error. The code works, both codes work. There is no syntax error persay. the Issue is the cluster center calculation by python I believe. The initial data has to be loaded and transformed to PCA. The error may be in transformation or in the way python does the cluster centers. All this code is required to do those things if I remove any of that the person looking at this will be requesting more info. The only thing I could have left out is the graphs but those are not long. That is why I decided to leave it. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: As a matter a fact some here had the same issue with respect to cluster center calculation python and r not being the same and it could not be answered due to not enough info being provided. I went out of my way to make sure that is not the case with my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34869378/clustering-with-kmeans-in-r-different-centers-after-clustering

Comment: First no one will look at this because your data is locall. There is no reproducible example. 2nd, its too long. You should consider going step by step through the code until you find where the two dont produce the same results. Then ask the question using the data before the discrepancy and the code that does not produce same results. Hope this helps

Comment: The link above provides you with the local data set I am looking at who ever runs this will have to change the path to where ever they downloaded to the path where they have data locally. The data is provided. If you are having issues downloading data that is different please let me know.

Comment: k-means typically has a random starting point, thus two different runs can lead to different answers. If you run just your R code several times,  you will likely get different answers. This is neither an error nor a discrepancy between R and python.  It is how k-means works.

Comment: Every single time I run the R code the graphs look exactly the same. Every time I run the python code the graphs are exactly the same. But the R code graphs and the python graphs are different and not by a little but by a lot a huge difference for the same exact data.

Comment: Dave2e that's the point the data is exactly the same the end result for both code sets should be the same at worst a little different its the same data I am doing the same thing with the data there is reason for there such a huge discrepancy.  This code runs if you run the data the graphs for the PCA is the exactly the same but the cluster centers are just completely different. I would like to know why or what have I done wrong thanks for all the feedback here.

Comment: Compare the biplots between the R and Python principal components. When I run your data through `kmeans()`, I get 530 observations in the first cluster, 2 in another cluster and the remaining 4 clusters have 1 observation each. How does that compare with your Python results? My first guess would be that you have 6 observations with outliers on one or more variables.

Comment: Followup. Check rows 421, 169, 138, 470, 463, and 119. They each have standard scores over 10 for one or more variables. Those are enormous outliers. Probably data coding errors.

Comment: dcarlson this is anomaly detection the bipolts match on python and R exactly the same. And yes 530 in one cluster makes sense these are the tables that act normally. Thats what the analysis does. The others are the anomalies. Now the bar chart that does not match is supposed to tell you why the table is different than the normal tables. That is the grapth that does not match at the end. There is no error in the data this data comes directly from MS SQL dmv's. There are some large numbers yes they are not in error.

Comment: Perhaps this question may be better on a different forum? On the Data Science or Cross Validated forum Please advise Thank you. Adding this link as another example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914764/my-k-means-cluster-analysis-results-are-different-in-r-and-python

Comment: @LeoTorres to improve your chances of getting a good answer, please remove **any** uncessary lines of code. For instance, anything to do with ggplot, anything to do with ``print`` or ``options`` is cluttering up the example and making it more difficult for people to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update now I have this working in R and Python**

Looking at this specific problem, check the outputs of the PCA - they're different, so k-means won't be the same. The reason is in your R code - you repeat the line `data <- data[, -1]`, dropping the table names and the first column of the data. Remove the extra line, and the clusters look the same.

---

**General comments on R and Python implementation of kmeans**

In general, it looks like R and python use different algorithms by default. R uses `"Hartigan-Wong"` by default, and Python's scikit-learn probably uses `"elkan"`. Set `algorithm='Lloyd'` in R and `algorithm='full'` in Python (which I believe currently will run Lloyd's algorithm as well) to ensure they're at least attempting the same thing.

You also have different initialisation methods - R is random and for Python you are using `'k-means++'`. Set `init='random'` in Python to make these match.

They have different numbers of max iteartions - R defaults to 10, Python to 300. Set these as equal also.

Finally, you won't see any random variation in your python script if you set the `random_state` in the Python KMeans call (and check you haven't `set.seed` in R also).

Once you've done this, try running both multiple times, and compare the distributions of values. Hopefully you'll see overlap between the two implementations.

Check out the docs for the [R implementation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/kmeans) and the [scikit-learn implementation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html).

And a final point here - kmeans is unsupervised. The class labels have no absolute meaning. Run the code multiple times, and class 0 will not always be assigned to the same data points, even if data points are grouped identically.

Here's a reproducible example of this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import cluster, datasets

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

X, y = datasets.make_blobs(100,2,centers=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(X)

random_states = list(range(0,60,10))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,2, figsize=(20,16))
for i, r in enumerate(random_states):

    clusters = KMeans(n_clusters=6,init='k-means++', random_state=r).fit(X)

    df = (df
      .assign(**{
          'Cluster': clusters.labels_,
          'Cluster Centroid D1': lambda x: x['Cluster'].apply(lambda label: clusters.cluster_centers_[label][0]),
          'Cluster Centroid D2': lambda x: x['Cluster'].apply(lambda label: clusters.cluster_centers_[label][1]),
      })
     )
    
    row = i//2
    col = i - row*2
    sns.scatterplot(data=df, x=0, y=1, hue='Cluster', s=200, palette='coolwarm', legend=True, ax=ax[row,col])
    sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="Cluster Centroid D1", y="Cluster Centroid D2", hue='Cluster', s=1000, 
                    palette='coolwarm', legend=False, alpha=0.1, ax=ax[row,col])
```

Here's a version with your data:

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

TableStats = pd.read_csv('TableStats2.csv')

sc = StandardScaler()
pca = PCA()
tables = TableStats.iloc[:,0]
y = tables

features = ['Range Scans', 'Singleton Lookups', 'Row Locks', 'Row Lock Waits (ms)',
            'Page Locks', 'Page Lock Waits (ms)', 'Page IO Latch Wait (ms)']

# Separating out the features
x = TableStats.loc[:, features].values

x = sc.fit_transform(x)
dpca = pca.fit_transform(x)
x1 = dpca[:,0]
y1 = dpca[:,1]

random_states = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for r in random_states:
    df = pd.DataFrame(dpca,columns = ['Range Scans', 'Singleton Lookups', 'Row Locks', 'Row Lock Waits (ms)',
                                      'Page Locks', 'Page Lock Waits (ms)', 'Page IO Latch Wait (ms)']) 
    clusters = KMeans(n_clusters=6,init='k-means++', random_state=r).fit(df)

    df = (df
          .assign(**{
              'Cluster': clusters.labels_,
              'Cluster Centroid D1': lambda x: x['Cluster'].apply(lambda label: clusters.cluster_centers_[label][0]),
              'Cluster Centroid D2': lambda x: x['Cluster'].apply(lambda label: clusters.cluster_centers_[label][1]),
          })
         )
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 11))
    ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x=x1, y=y1, hue='Cluster', s=200, palette='coolwarm', legend=True)
    ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="Cluster Centroid D1", y="Cluster Centroid D2", hue='Cluster', 
                         s=1000, palette='coolwarm', legend=False, alpha=0.1)    

    plt.legend(loc='upper right', title='Cluster')
    ax.set_title("Clustered Points", fontsize='xx-large', y=1.05);
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank s_pike, thank you for pointing that out. I went ahead and changed the random_sate in python and set.seed() both to 2121.  The results for each changed a little bit. but the difference between Python remain very different.

Comment: I went ahead and made the seed update to both code sets

Comment: I would suggest not setting random state or seed in either R or python, and then run each multiple times. Also, change your KMeans `init` parameter in python to `'random'` as this will be closer to the method used in R. And in R, change algorithm to `'Lloyd'`, and increase `'iter.max'` to 300 to match the `sklearn` implementation.